# How to force Jest to exit a certain test file

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a few e2e tests, one of them hangs and we can't find out why, so we want to use [--forceExit](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--forceexit). But, we don't want to force exit all the tests just **a particular one** because we use github actions + npm script to run these e2e tests.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without further information on your part.

However, if you want to quit a running test, you can always use a return statement.

For example (all tests should pass):

```js
describe("exit a test", () => {
  it("good test 1", () => {
    const aSum = 1;

    expect(aSum).toBe(1);
  });

  it("uses a flag and a return statement to prevent test from failing", () => {
    const flag = true;

    if (flag) {
      return;
    }

    expect(flag).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it("good test 2", () => {
    const aSum = 1;

    expect(aSum).toBe(1);
  });
});
```